# Banach space of p-Lipschitz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Given $p\in\mathbb{R}$, consider the space:
>
> $$ Lip(p) = \left\{f:[0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} : \mbox{ $f$ is $p$-Lipschitz} \right\}$$
>
> i.e.: there is $M>0$ such that $|f(s)-f(t)|<M|s-t|^p \quad\forall s,t\in 0,1]$
>
> We can define a norm on $Lip(p)$ by  $$\Vert f\Vert = |f(0)| + \sup \left\{ \frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^p}: t\neq s, \quad t,s\in [0,1]  \right\}$$
>
> It's easy to show that $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is a norm in $Lip(p)$, but I
>   was not able to proove that $(Lip(p),\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ is a Banach
>   space.

Given a Cauchy sequence $(f_n) \subseteq Lip(p)$, I couldn't find a candidate to conclude the convergence proof. Any hint? (I DO NOT want an entire proof)

Comment: If it's a Cauchy sequence in $Lip(p)$, it's a Cauchy sequence with the uniform topology. (You need to prove that) This allows you to construct a limit function. Now prove that (a) the limit function is also in $Lip(p)$ and that (b) convergence is actually in $Lip(p)$.

Comment: I was stuck in this problem, i'll try to write it! Thanks @HansEngler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$ m,n \geq n_0 \implies \Vert f_m - f_n \Vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$$

Then, we have:

1. $|f_m(0) - f_n(0)|< \varepsilon /4$
2. $\sup \left\{ \frac{|(f_m-f_n)(t)-(f_m-f_n)(s)|}{|t-s|^p}: t\neq s, \quad t,s\in [0,1]  \right\} < \varepsilon /4$

Given $t\in]0,1]$, we have for all $m,n > n_0$:
$$|f_m(t) - f_n(t)| \leq |(f_m-f_n)(t) - (f_m-f_n)(0)| + |f_m(0) - f_n(0)| < \varepsilon $$

Comment: OK, this proves that $(f_n)_n$ is  Cauchy sequence in the uniform norm. Therefore, there is a limit function $f$. By uniform convergence, it is continuous. Next, prove that $f \in Lip(p)$.

Comment: This is the most important part of the solution, later I'll write everything in details. Thank you very much for your help!