# How to prove that whether it is a Banach space or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, functional-equations

We consider the Banach space of all continuous functions on $X$ such that for each $f$ in the space, 
\begin{equation*}
||f||=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\left\vert
f(x)-f(y)\right\vert }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }.
\end{equation*}

How I can prove that it is a Banach space?

Comment: Please add the link to the research paper you have read up so that people may understand the context better. You will also get more answers.

Comment: Are you sure this is what they wrote? Continuous functions satisfying $f(1)=1$ don't form a vector space.

Comment: It is not a Banach space. Perhaps you mean $f(1) = 0$?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It has just one condition, f(0)=0.

Comment: @sai-kartik Now, I stated it exactly as it appeared in the paper.

Comment: Try searching. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3136994/27978

Comment: @Blazej Can you please explain your statement 'Continuous functions satisfying f(1)=1 don't form a vector space.'

Comment: You do realise that $m$ is not a norm? It is not defined for all continuous functions. You need to edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

$m$ is not a norm on the set of the continuous function on $[0, 1]$ with $f(0)=0$, because not all continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ are Lipschitz. For example, take $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. It's continuous, $f(0)=0$, but
$$\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|}{|x-y|}=\frac{1}{|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|}$$
And taking $x=0$, we get that
$$m(f)\geqslant \lim_{y \to 0+0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}=+\infty$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I add 'Lipschitz condition' with the given data, then is it work for every case???

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar Yes, and you can even generalize it: If you take a metric space $(M, d)$, and pick a point $x_0 \in M$, you will get that the set of Lipschitz functions from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x_0)=0$ is a banach space, with the Lipschitz norm (of course, insterad of $|x-y|$ we have $d(x,y)$)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(CL^0,\|\cdot\|_{CL^0})$. Then

- $\{f_n\}$ is bounded (in the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm), and
- $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous.

To see the first point, let $M:=\sup_n\|f_n\|_n$, which is finite. For any $n$, one has
$$|f_n(x)|=|f_n(x)-f_n(0)| \le m(f_n)|x-0| \le M|x|\le M,$$

so $\|f_n\|_\infty \le M$. To see the second point, fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $\delta:=\epsilon/M$. Then for all $n$ and all $x,y\in[0,1]$, if $|x-y|<\delta$ then
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \le m(f_n)|x-y| \le M\delta = \epsilon.$$

It follows from the Arzela-Ascoli theorem that $\{f_n\}$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence, i.e. there exists $\{n_k\}$ and a continuous function $f$ such that $f_{n_k}\to f$ uniformly. Of course, we immediately have $f(0)=0$ and $m(f) \le M$, so $f\in CL^0$. It remains to show $f_{n_k} \to f$ in $\|\cdot\|_{CL^0}$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. There exists $K$ such that $\|f_{n_j}-f_{n_k}\|_{CL^0} < \epsilon/3$ for all $j,k\ge K$. Now let $x,y\in[0,1]$ with $x\neq y$. Since $f_{n_k}\to f$ uniformly, there exists $K^{x,y} \ge K$ such that $\|f_{n_{K^{x,y}}}-f\|_\infty < \epsilon|x-y|/3$. It follows that, if $k\ge K$,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{|(f_{n_k}-f)(x) - (f_{n_k}-f)(y)|}{|x-y|} \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\le \frac{|(f_{n_k}-f_{n_{K^{x,y}}})(x) - (f_{n_k}-f{n_{K^{x,y}}})(y)|}{|x-y|} + \frac{|(f_{n_k}-f)(x) - (f_{n_k}-f)(y)|}{|x-y|} \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\le \|f_{n_k}-f_{n_{K^{x,y}}}\|_{CL^0} + \frac{2\|f_{n_k}-f\|_\infty}{|x-y|} \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\le \frac{\epsilon}3 + \frac{2\epsilon}3 = \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Crucially, since $K$ does not depend on $x$ or $y$, we can take supremum over $x,y\in[0,1]$ with $x\neq y$ and conclude that, if $k\ge K$,
$$\|f_{n_k}-f\|_{CL^0} \le \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

In general it is kind of hard to guess whether a space is complete or not. Usually you may try to describe the property defining your norm/functions in geometric terms and try to see if you can construct a sequence of functions in your space so that their pointwise limit breaks the property defining your space. If you cannot find such thing, you could try proving that your space is complete and see what you get. If you find an obstruction in your proof, then you can try to see if that obstruction can help constructing a counterexample. It is a back and forth process, a lot of experimentation needed.

In this particular case, I would advice to try proving that the pointwise limit is in your space. Arzela-Ascoli's theorem might come in handy.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: what defines what a comment and an answer are? I am genuinely asking, as I don't see a clear line separating them. OP asked how to prove that a space is Banach or not, and I gave them an answer on how to approach that problem. They also asked for suggestions, and I gave some too. Are answers supposed to fully solve the problem?

Comment: What would an instructor think if you gave them the above as an answer. The question is simple, they are not asking if it is Banach, they are asking how to show it is Banach. There is nothing useful in the above that would assist with proving this. Nothing.

Comment: I literally gave the two most important parts of the problem in my answer: looking at the pointwise limit and using Arzela-Ascoli. Again, are we suppose to spoon feed the whole solutions or just give directions? And just look at the title, they're asking how to prove whether the space is or not a Banach space. Personally when I come here for help, I want people to give me a push, not to write a step by step solution to my problem. I was not aware that there is a moral instructor grading our answers. I'm not going to keep arguing about this anyway.