# What is the geometrical meaning of the space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, functional-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the Banach space of all lipschitz functions on $X$ such that for each $f$ in the space, 
\begin{equation*}
||f||=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\left\vert
f(x)-f(y)\right\vert }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }.
\end{equation*}
is a Banach space.

Comment: Why would you take the intersection of $CL^0$ and one of its subsets?

Comment: @CaptainLama it appears in a paper [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X76900123)

Comment: This seems possibly inappropriate to the algebraic-geometry tag. Is this tag just on there because you are looking for "geometrical intuition" for a problem in analysis, or is there some connection with algebraic geometry that I've overlooked?

Comment: @KReiser I just tagged it because I'm looking for geometrical intuition.

Comment: As with your other question, $m$ is **not** defined for all continuous functions. So it cannot be a norm.

Comment: @copper.hat what is the geometrical meaning of  $CL^{0} \cap \lbrace f,f\in CL^{0}, f(1)\leq 1\rbrace $ ?

Comment: Are you reading the comments?

Comment: @copper.hat I already read comments. As I am new in this research field that's why I want to see the meaning of  $CL^{0} \cap \lbrace f,f\in CL^{0}, f(1)\leq 1\rbrace $ from its geometry (like, in terms of graph or picture).

Comment: The space you are referring to is not a normed space.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you please explain why it is not a normed space? Which property of normed space it doesn't satisfy? Please explain it.

Comment: @copper.hat The statement of the problem appeared in this paper [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X76900123). The author mentioned that it is a Banach space.

Comment: As noted in your other question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3663825/27978, $m$ is not a norm on the space of continuous functions.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. I have seen your comment on the previous question where you mentioned [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136994/space-of-lipschitz-functions-form-a-banach-space). If I replace 'space of continuous functions' with 'space of Lipschitz functions', then above statement is correct???

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar: Yes. You should edit both questions.

Comment: @copper.hat With due respect, can I replace it with 'space of real-valued bounded continuous functions' as well?

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar: No. The function $x \mapsto \min(1,\sqrt{|x|})$ is continuous, bounded, zero at zero but $m$ is infinite.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you so much. Sir, why they take the intersection of these terms $CL^{0} \cap \lbrace f,f\in CL^{0}, f(1)\leq 1\rbrace$ ? Why we need it? Can you please explain it?

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar: The intersection doesn't really make sense, perhaps they mean $\{ f \in CL^0 | f(1) \le 1 \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks Sir. Can I replace $f(1) \leq 1$ by $f(1)=1$ ? It means that I am considering those Lipschitz functions which satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ and using the same norm (mentioned above).